# Use of extra claims in a token for authorization checking purposes

Tags: api, oauth2, access-control, identity

Currently we are moving to an API driven architecture using SPAs and WebAPIs. We are also moving from SAML2 to OAuth 2.0 and if it is appropriate, OIDC.

We have a couple of APIs and one of the APIs can check if a user is under guardianship. This API is being called directly from the SPA and is used to detect which data should be received and which components should be rendered.

My suggestion was to let our identity provider call the API and save the info in the ID token. Would this be a good approach?

Some arguments against this are that we need to have a third-party application supply the ID token info and we need to use that party to add or remove fields from it, so calling our own APIs every time would save (development) time.

Arguments for this are that we can use industry standards to get identity information.